# How do you set the style for the selected MudButton in the MudButtonGroup?

Tags: blazor, mudblazor, buttongroup

[image: Button Group]

I am looking for a way to set the style of the selected button in the MudButtonGroup.

I have looked at the classes set for the Buttons and ButtonGroup and have not found anything that differentiates the selected button.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this, where you send the button's reference as a parameter when it's clicked and change its properties there.

```
<MudButtonGroup Color="Color.Primary" Variant="Variant.Outlined" OverrideStyles="false">
    <MudButton @ref="_button1" OnClick="(e)=>HandleClick(e,_button1)">One</MudButton>
    <MudButton @ref="_button2" OnClick="(e)=>HandleClick(e,_button2)">Two</MudButton>
    <MudButton @ref="_button3" OnClick="(e)=>HandleClick(e,_button3)">Three</MudButton>
</MudButtonGroup>
@code{
    MudButton _button1,_button2,_button3;
    List<MudButton> _buttons;
    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        if(firstRender)
        {
            _buttons = new(){_button1,_button2,_button3};
        }
    }
    void HandleClick(MouseEventArgs e, MudButton clickedButton)
    {
        foreach(var button in _buttons)
        {
            if(button.Equals(clickedButton)){
                button.Color = Color.Secondary;
            }else{
                button.Color = Color.Default;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Snippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/mkmdEhGRzybGowzw)

Comment: I had to make one change to get it to work. Instead of `button.Color` I had to use `button.Style`.

Comment: Very complicated for a simple task.  The MudButtonGroup should have a SelectedColor attribute.  Hope this will come in the near future, same for radiobuttons.

Comment: Based on the answer and the comment from @demet I used 

<MudButton Style="@(myValue== 0 ? "background-color: lightblue": "")"